# SQL - AVG call rate by time of day and day of week

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with records for each telephone call.
I want to create a matrix where I have the average call rate per 30 minute time segment over the day by day of week.  Each call has a start time which is a date/time

i.e.

I want to display Mon-Sun as row headers and 30 min intervals as column headers. The content is the average count of calls for each day (Mon - Sun) in each particular 30 minute segment.  This is where I have got but it isn't what I want.  It sums the number of calls by time segment and I cant work out how to get averages.

I hope some can point me in the right direction -

SQL is not something I use often so be gentle :-)

```
set dateformat dmy
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Start with Monday
SELECT datepart(dw,starttime) as 'Day',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Midnight-12:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12:30am-1am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1am-1:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1:30am-2am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2am-2:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2:30am-3am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3am-3:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3:30am-4am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4am-4:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4:30am-5am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5am-5:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5:30am-6am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6am-6:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6:30am-7am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7am-7:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7:30am-8am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8:30am-9am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9am-9:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10:30am-11am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11am-11:30am',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11:30am-Noon',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Noon-12:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1pm-1:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1:30pm-2pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2pm-2:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2:30pm-3pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3pm-3:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4:30pm-4pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4pm-5:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5:30pm-6pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6pm-6:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6:30pm-7pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7pm-7:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7:30pm-8pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8pm-8:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8:30pm-9pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9pm-9:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9:30pm-10pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10pm-10:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10:30pm-11pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) > 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11pm-11:30pm',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(hour,StartTime) = 7 and DATEPART(Minute,StartTime) <= 30)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11:30pm-Midnight'

FROM [dbo].[CallList]
where StartTime>'1/6/2015'
       and StartTime<'30/6/2015'
GROUP BY datepart(dw,starttime)
ORDER BY datepart(dw,starttime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `WHILE` loop to insert into a temp table then doing the aggregation after the fact is a viable option.  See below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,DateIn DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 00:01:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 00:21:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 01:01:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 05:41:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 06:51:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 13:21:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 18:01:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 21:11:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 23:41:00'),
(NEWID(), '2016-05-17 23:51:00')


DECLARE @Start DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME

SET @Start = '2016-05-17 00:00:00'
SET @End = '2016-05-17 00:30:00'

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,[Time Increment] VARCHAR(100)
)

WHILE @End <= '2016-05-17 23:30:00'
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT
    ID
    ,CAST(@Start AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(@End AS VARCHAR) [Time Increment]
    FROM #Data
    WHERE DateIn >= @Start
    AND DateIn < @End

    SET @Start = DATEADD(Minute, 30, @Start)
    SET @End = DATEADD(Minute, 30, @End)
    END

SELECT
[Time Increment]
,COUNT(ID) [Count]
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY [Time Increment]

DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #Data
```

In this example, the result is the following:

```
Time Increment                            |Count
May 17 2016  1:00AM - May 17 2016  1:30AM | 1
May 17 2016  1:00PM - May 17 2016  1:30PM | 1
May 17 2016  5:30AM - May 17 2016  6:00AM | 1
May 17 2016  6:00PM - May 17 2016  6:30PM | 1
May 17 2016  6:30AM - May 17 2016  7:00AM | 1
May 17 2016  9:00PM - May 17 2016  9:30PM | 1
May 17 2016 12:00AM - May 17 2016 12:30AM | 2
```